# Makefile issues - how to include a function in a different file in your main file

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

My main source file

myapp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myfunctions.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name \n";  //Prompts user to enter name
    
    helloName();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the file containing the helloName() function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myfunctions.h"
using namespace std;

void  helloName()
{
    
  string name;    /// string variable defined as 'name'
 
  cin >> name;   //User enters name
  cout << "Hello  " << name << endl;  //Outputs "Hello" followed by the name entered
}
```

my header file  for helloName
myfunctions.h

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H

void helloName(void);


#endif
```

Makefile

```
# makefile for myapp

myapp: myapp.cpp myfunctions.cpp 
    g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o myapp myapp.cpp

myfunctions: myfunctions.cpp myfunctions.h
    g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o myfunctions myfunctions.cpp


clean: 
    rm *# *~ myapp
```

When
make myapp
is entered into terminal, the following error is received:

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccv3S2EK.o: in function main:
myapp.cpp:(.text+0x22): **undefined reference to `helloName()'**

Can anyone spot my issue? Haven't been coding very long so am sure it is probably basic

Comment: Please edit the question and show us the output that make generates _before_ the error in question, so we can see the linker command line; something is wrong with it.  I mean, the above makefile is _clearly_ wrong but if you're still seeing the error using the makefile in the answer below, please edit the question and supply the command you typed and the complete output you got including the commands make printed (also please properly use code blocks to format that output).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You attempt to build `myfunctions.cpp` into an *executable* program named `myfunctions`.
2. For `myapp` you build the executable program using only the `myapp.cpp` source file.

To solve your problem I recommend you rely on *implicit rules* to create object files from source files, and link the object files into an executable file.

Then your `Makefile` only have to look like this:

```
LD = $(CXX)

myapp: myapp.o myfunctions.o

myapp.o: myapp.cpp myfunctions.h
myfunctions.o: myfunctions.cpp myfunctions.h
```

The first rule tells `make` to build the executable file `myapp` by linking the two object files `myapp.o` and `myfunctions.o`. The implicit rules will create the object files from their respective source file.

The second and third rules tells `make` that the two object files depend on their source file *and* the header file. So if the header file is modified, then both object files will be rebuilt.

The variable definition tells `make` that the linker is the same program as the C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your input RE implicit rules, I have changed it but still receiving an error of "undefined reference to `helloName()" in myapp.cpp, any idea how to address this?

Comment: @finnh98 Replace your current `Makefile` with the example shown in my answer. Don't list any build-commands yourself. What's shown in my answer is a *complete* `Makefile` which should solve your problem (assuming the code in your question is correct).

Comment: thanks again, but it looks like my code isn't correct, I am thinking it is a syntax issue but cannot spot it?

Comment: Just to note that this makefile is not complete.  Based on your original makefile you also need to add `CXXFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts`.  However, that won't make a difference given the source code you've shown here.